# Método post de formulario no devuelve ruta adecuada en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Estoy intentando crear un formulario en laravel. Mi problema es que cuando intento enviar el formulario por post, se dirige a la ruta /POST?nombre=Juan&email=juan%40hola.com cuando lo que quiero es ir a /contacto

Rutas

```
Route::get('contactame', [PagesController::class, 'contact'])->name('contactos');   
Route::post('contacto', [PagesController::class, 'mensajes']);
```

Controller

```
class PagesController extends Controller
{
    public function contact() {
        return view('contactos');
    }

    public function mensajes() {
        return 'Procesando el mensaje';
    }
}
```

Vista

```
<form action="POST" action="contacto">
    <label for="nombre">
        Nombre
        <input type="text" name="nombre" id="">
    </label>

    <label for="email">
        Email
        <input type="text" name="email" id="">
    </label>
        
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

También intenté darle un nombre a la ruta post y poner el action del formulario como

```
action="{{ route('contacto') }}"
```

pero tengo el mismo resultado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comentarios.

1. Esta línea de código es errónea

   ```
    <form action="POST" action="contacto">
   ```

Pues en el action va la ruta o archivo que proceda tu petición y `POST` tiene que ir como valor de atributo `method` entonces va así:

```
<form action="{{ route('contacto') }}" method="POST">
```

2. Dentro de tu método  te hace falta inyectar a la clase `Request` y un objeto para acceder a la data de la petición así

   ```
    public function mensajes(Request $request) {
   ```
3. Finalmente te hace falta indicar dentro del cuerpo del formulario el token por cada petición, eso lo consigues así por medio de la directiva `@csrf`

   ```
    <form action="{{ route('contacto') }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
   ```